# Allow user to edit app.config file for ClickOnce installation

Tags: c#, config, clickonce, publish

I have published a small program through ClickOnce in VS 2012.  This has generated a app.exe.config.deploy file but no app.config file.  I need the user to be able to enter a sql connection string, a few email addresses and other things into the app.config file but currently don't have this option.  I know this seems to be an issue as old as time but I can't find a resolution online.  This is the first application that I have ever published.  I've tried taking off signing and hashing of the config file but that didn't work.  Any helpful advice in SO land?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically not the answer I was looking for but I changed my build setting to Release by going to Build --> Configuration Manager --> Active Solution Configuration --> Release.  I built the solution again and this gave me a Release folder in \Bin with all the files including the .config file I was hunting.  Hope this helps somebody else.  It is worth noting that my program is very small, will not be frequently updated and can easily be repackaged and distributed to the one user who will need it.